# Sencha Touch: Displaying and editing HasMany field on formpanel

Tags: javascript, forms, sencha-touch, has-many

My Question is: How to display and edit a hasMany field on the formpanel of sencha touch API

Sencha touch does not have a listbox or any other feature to innately do this.

My example

**Candidate:**

- firstName: [textfield]
- lastName: [textfield]
- ...
- list of interviewers

candidate has many interviewers

I looked into tpl and xtemplates but could not get anything to work

My idea is to have a textfield that also functions as a search with ajax with an add button ( + ) beside it, if it's any but the first textfield an ( - ) button.

Even getting a textfield and a button to display on the same row seems difficult

My Models:

```
     Ext.require('Candidates.model.Interviewer', function() {
        Ext.define('Candidates.model.Candidate', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

            config: {
                fields: [
                    {name: 'id', type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'firstName', type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'lastName', type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'email', type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'dept', type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'room', type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'greet', type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'present', type: 'boolean'},
                    {name: 'date', type: 'date'},
                    {name: 'status', type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'completed', type: 'boolean'}
                ],
                hasMany: {
                    model: 'Candidates.model.Interviewer',
                    name: 'Interviewers'
                }
            },
      });
```

Interviewer

```
    Ext.define('Candidates.model.Interviewer', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

        config: {
            fields: [
                {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
                {name: 'firstName', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'lastName', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'username', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'password', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'email', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'dept', type: 'string'}
            ]
        }
    });
```

in fieldset items [

```
    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name : 'firstName',
        label: 'First Name',
    },
    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name : 'lastName',
        label: 'Last Name',
    },
    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'interviewers',
        id: 'interviewerfield',
        label: 'Interviewer(s)',
        tpl: [
            '<div class="candidate">',
                '<tpl for="interviewers">',
                    '<div class="interviewers">',
                        '{firstName}',
                    '</div>',
                '</tpl>',
            '</div>'
        ].join(''),
        store: 'Candidates'
    },
```

Idea's I tried to even just display a list of interviewers to the field

Anybody have any idea a way to display a many field onto the formfield?

Comment: My form displays/updates the data for the other fields so I at least know the models and store are working for candidates.

Comment: oO - the name of your store is the same as the app?!

Answer (score 0):

I suffer from the same problem, i find solution by Ext.dataview.DataView instead of using Ext.List.